# insert column in with same value as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key

is possible in Rails, to insert row and to assign value of id to specific column, e.g. if i have table which have ID and LINK columns where LINK is link to same table:

```
ID | LINK
1  |   1
2  |   1
3  |   1
```

Inserting columns 2 and 3 are easy, but is there any way to insert column 1 with single INSERT statement?

Is this possible via rails syntax or i need custom SQL (on PostgreSQL) ?

[Of course, this can be done with INSERT/UPDATE but i need to disable updates on this table]

tx
Zaharije

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-joining table.  You don't need to write the SQL yourself.  Just define this relationship in the model like so:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee"
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee",
    :foreign_key => "manager_id"  # or what you call LINK
end
```

Also, link probably isn't a good column name, try to pick something more descriptive if you can.

Comment: This is not a problem. Problem is when i wanna to INSERT new Employee which is self-manager: emp = Employee.new({:manager_id => emp.id }) I need to manager be manager of itself (not good case for Employe) and to insert that in single INSERT statement. I can do : emp = Employee.new() emp.save emp.manager = emp emp.save But that will trigger INSERT and UPDATE (2 statements). I need to execute that in one statement. Only way ehat i can see is to create custom SQL (PostgreSQL db) with nextval and currval for values of ID and MANAGER_ID

Comment: You could use a callback like before_save or after_create to set the self-joining foreign key but it's still going to have to insert a new row to get the ID and then do the updates.  Alternatively, you can query for the next row ID in MySQL but this is unreliable and a bad idea.  Are you pre-optimizing to avoid the 2 updates?

Comment: A little bit outdated - we are having DB where we store money transactions and we don't wanna to allow any kind of UPDATES on it. As i sad its outdated - we restructured DB and don't have same problem. Tx.